# UITableView inside a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

This is my View Controller, as you can see, there is a UITableView in the lower part.

[image]

I put the delegate and datasource in the .h file

```
@interface CourseFindrViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

While my .m file is this:

```
@interface CourseFindrViewController ()
{ sqlite3 *_db;}
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *jNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *jDescLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *jEarningsLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *cTableLabel;
@end

@implementation CourseFindrViewController
@synthesize jDetails =_jDetails;



-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

        _jDetails = (Jobs *)self.jDetails;
        [self.jNameLabel setText:_jDetails.jName];
        [self.jDescLabel setText:_jDetails.jDesc];
        [self.jEarningsLabel setText:_jDetails.jEarnings];
    NSLog(@"%d", _jDetails.jID);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.jNameLabel = nil;
    self.jDescLabel = nil;
    self.jEarningsLabel = nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSArray *)course;
{
    NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"CourseFindr" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    NSMutableArray *retrieve = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &_db) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
                NSString *query= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT course. * FROM course INNER JOIN jobsCourse ON jobsCourse.courseID = course.cID WHERE jobsCourse.jobID = %d", _jDetails.jID];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    int _cID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                    char *cNameChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
                    char *cDescChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
                    char *cSchoolChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text (statement, 3);
                    char *cProgramChars = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
                    NSString *_cName =cNameChars?[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:cNameChars]:@"";
                    NSString *_cDesc = cDescChars?[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:cDescChars]:@"";
                    NSString *_cSchool = cSchoolChars?[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:cSchoolChars]:@"";
                    NSString *_cProgram = cProgramChars?[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:cProgramChars]:@"";
                    Course *courses = [[Course alloc]
                               initWithCID:_cID
                               cName:_cName
                               cDesc:_cDesc
                               cSchool:_cSchool
                               cProgram:_cProgram];
                    [retrieve addObject:courses];
                }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            }

        }
    return retrieve;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *title1 = _jDetails.jName;
    self.navigationItem.title = title1;
}
- (void)dealloc {

}
```

The code stops here. I added a breakpoint.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.course count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"courseCell"];
    NSLog(@"Here.");
    Course *courses = [self.course objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =courses.cName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =courses.cSchool;
    return cell;
}
```

And it's still not passing the data to the table.. the table isn't appearing.
[image]

Comment: did you set tableView delegate and dataSource.?

Comment: Have you connected datasource and delegate from xib or programmatically?

Comment: @santhu what do you mean?

Comment: @LucaIaco yes I have.

Comment: That is the most undescriptive title i've ever seen for a question. How does that even remotely summarise the issue at hand ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add connection between table view and your datasource and delegate.
To do that simple control drag from your table view to view controller and select datasource and do the same but this time select delegate.

Comment: Can you put log: NSLog(@"Array count: %d", [self.course count]); in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method and let me know is it called? Is your log NSLog(@"Here."); called?

Comment: The `NSLog(@"Here");` isn't called since it cannot pass through the breakpoint. Array count is 0.. :( How do I fix that? :/

Comment: Have you got any outlet to your table view? If not create one and call [tableView reloadData]; at the end of viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I found the problem. it should be `==SQLITE OK`

Answer (score 0):

You must connect datasource and delegate in the xib.